# MySQL arithmetic average query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which describes a restaurant warehouse. In this tabel I have field ID autoincrement, WID, quantity, unit_price, dimension, name.
IDs are unique but let me show a php script which describes what I'm doing while inserting

```
if(isset($_POST['refill_date'])){
    $id = intval($_POST['item_id']);
    $wid = intval($_POST['item_wid']);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $qty = floatval($_POST['quantity']);
    $dimen = $_POST['dimension'];
    $tp = floatval($_POST['total_price']);
    $up = floatval($_POST['unit_price']);
    $dist_id = intval($_POST['dist_id']);
    $waybill = $_POST['waybill'];
    $refill_date = $_POST['refill_date'];
    if(!empty($wid) && !empty($id)){
        $insert = $MySQL->query("INSERT INTO warehouse (wid,name,quantity,dimension,unit_price,refill_date,distributor_id,waybill) VALUES ($wid,'$name',$qty,'$dimen',$up,'$refill_date',$dist_id,'$waybill')");
        $update = true;
    }else{
        $insert = $MySQL->query("INSERT INTO warehouse (name,quantity,dimension,unit_price,refill_date,distributor_id,waybill,date) VALUES ('$name',$qty,'$dimen',$up,'$refill_date',$dist_id,'$waybill',now())");
        $wid = mysql_insert_id();
        $update = $MySQL->query("UPDATE warehouse SET wid = $wid WHERE id = $wid");
    }
    if($insert === true && $update === true)
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "failure";
    exit;
}
```

So you can see that if product does not exist it creates new one and assigns new ID to WID, and in future when the same product will be added the WID will be the same but ID will be increased.
Now my task is to output distinct data, but the quantity should be summed up and the unit price should be calculated arithmetic average. I have 13 records with WID 65 and all these have different unit prices so all unit prices should be summed and divided by 13. All this will output like one record. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Have a look at the [`AVG` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).  You'll (probably) need a where clause, and a `GROUP BY`

Comment: And please, please learn about SQL injection.  A malicious person could pass a carefully crafted `name` value to your code do unwanted things with your data. [Obligatory XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: See insert in the manual again

Answer (score 1):

```
$MySQL->query("SELECT DISTINCT id,wid,name,SUM(`quantity`) `QTY`,dimension,AVG(`unit_price`) `AVG`,refill_date,date,edit_date,distributor_id,waybill FROM warehouse GROUP BY wid LIMIT 20 OFFSET $offset");
```

This worked for me and gave all the results I wanted.